# Using 'normal' npm module in Angular / Ionic application

Tags: angular, npm, module, ionic3

I want to read a .plist file inside an Angular / Ionic application.

I found the following npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/plist

I installed it in my project and now I am wondering what is the best way to invoke it in my Angular code?

Now I have done it this way

```
const plist = require('plist');
const data = plist.parse(plistXML);
```

This works, though WebStorm complains that it does not know 'require'.
I was wondering if there is a better way.

I also found this way:

```
import * as plist from 'plist';
...
const data = plist.parse(plistXML);
```

Which one is the preferred way? Or is there even a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic (Angular) code we write in Typescript/Es6, and it uses webpack as a module bundler.
So Module code is written in ES6 way and babel converts it to CommonJS (require)

Using "import" way can be useful for 'tree shaking' using Roll up or Webpack 2. It helps in reducing the size of the bundled js.
I recommend import the required module and use it

```
import {required_module} as plist from 'plist';
...
const data = plist.parse(plistXML);
```